# iOS location without WiFi or GPS?

Tags: ios, core-location

I know that to get a user's location when GPS is not present, iOS approximates the user's position by looking at his proximity to nearby WiFi hotspots, then comparing that to a large database of hotspots that's stored server-side (see [Skyhook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyhook_Wireless)).

What I want to know is: is it possible to cache the WiFi network information, and send the location request off later? I'd like to, for example, have the user tap a button and save the WiFi data. Then later, when he was internet connectivity, determine where he was when the button was originally tapped.

Apple's Core Location API seems to be at too high of an abstraction level to be able to do this, but I could be missing something, or there might be another way to do this.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Rephrased question due to confusion.

Comment: No, not unless you cache the information yourself inside the app...

Comment: You would still need a GPS signal to receive raw signal data from the satellites, even if you didn't resolve them to a map location until later..

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys, I really phrased this question poorly the first time around. Basically, one method iOS uses to determine location is the user's proximity to known WiFi hotspots (of which there is a large database online somewhere). I want to know if it's possible to take a snapshot of nearby WiFi networks, and send the location request later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API to access that current WiFi spots visible, and no API to request a location from WiFI spots.

There used to be an app called WiFiTrak that displayed what WiFi spots were in radio range, but Apple removed it from the app store because it used private APIs.

Comment: Thanks, I think this just about closes it then. It looks like it's impossible to do what I want :(

Answer (score 1):

GPS and Wi-Fi don't "resolve" location data the device already has, they are methods of obtaining that data.

Comment: Actually, to determine location via WiFi, iOS looks at the device's proximity to nearby hotspots, and compares them to a large server-side database. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyhook_Wireless

Sorry for my poorly-phrased question, though. My edit should clear up the confusion.